# Is there a way of implementing callback methods for cucumber in java?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I recently came to a requirement where I have to do some preprocessing before test steps. I had to do this for both JUnit 5 (with Jupiter engine) and cucumber framework. I had done the same for JUnit 5 (as it supports for extension) using `BeforeEachCallback` and using `@extendWith` annotation.

But I am struggling in how to do the same for cucumber. Is there a way in cucumber by which I can register a callback method which will be called before every step is invoked? I know about `@Before` hooks but I want this method to be a common and generic one which will be called before every step for all features.

Something like below:

```
public void preProcesser() {
  //This method should be called with method context before each step
  //by method context I mean the targetMethod name (in JUnit I can easily get it from context.getTargetMethod()
}
```

Can anyone give me some direction/idea on the above please?

Comment: perhaps improve the question by explaining why you want to run something before every step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a `Background` step at the beginning of the feature file and that step acts as a prerequisite and runs before all the following scenarios.

```
@Tag
Feature: Test Feature

Background: Prerequisite step
    Given I perform some task
    Then navigate to home page

Scenario: Test Scenario
    Then I perform other tests
...
```

The execution flow for all your scenarios will be -

```
Given I perform some task
Then navigate to home page
Then I perform other tests
```